# warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, error-handling, compiler-errors

```
1>c:\users\aa\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\systemplanet\systemplanet\systemplanet.cpp(164):
    warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
```

I'm facing this problem, how can i resolve this problem ?

Comment: You need to show us the code, especially around line number 164.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is saying that comparing an `unsigned` variable against a `signed` variable is -<strike>not allowed</strike> considered bad practice.  This is because of [two's complement representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) of a `signed` variable.

- `(unsigned short) 0xFFFF` is 65535, and
- `(short) 0xFFFF` is -1.

They both have same the in-memory representation but mean totally opposite things. So the compiler is protecting you from yourself.

The details on this warning can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y92ktdf2.aspx

Comment: It _is_ allowed; the _usual arithmetic conversions_ are performed before the comparison takes place. Whether it gives what the users expects is another story.

Comment: `Otherwise, both operands shall be converted to the unsigned integer type corresponding to the
type of the operand with signed integer type.`

Comment: @phresnel, its allowed but this is a *warning*.  I'll change my English.

Comment: I somewhat wasn't informed about your edit, despite your "@phresnel". Anyways, +1 now :)